# Best book Style for Engineering

Tags: book-design

I am writing a book on the topic of Electric Machines Fundamentals. I want to know that from following which book style or template would be appropriate for me.
  Tufte-Style Book
The Legrand Orange Book
The Wiley Book Style
eBook

thanks in anticipation

Comment: I like my own book style, which I can send to you if you like: http://euclid.ucc.ie/pages/staff/mckay/analysis/analysis.pdf

Comment: It would be better if you provide some representative snapshots and ask what they are made from. (what document class? what package? any external program? and so on.) Otherwise we do not know where to start.

Comment: Tufte style has a nice design. However, if you are writing a textbook, I think the design is not very comfortable as a study material.